# Cordova project BLD00102 No such file or directory for symlink

Tags: visual-studio-2015, symlink, visual-studio-cordova

When trying to build a Cordova project with a symlink, I'm getting the following error:

```
1>JsUtil : cordova-build error BLD102: Error : BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'JsUtil'
```

Clearing the Cordova cache and deleting the bin&bld folders didn't help.
Also tried the solution outlined at [VS2015 Cordova MDAVSCLI : error : EBUSY, resource busy or locked symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813938/vs2015-cordova-mdavscli-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-symlink) but that didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did this start happening once you installed a Cordova plug-in?

Comment: Nope, no plugins whatsoever; a vanilla project created using the VS template.

Comment: What VS edition are you using, and are you on Update 1?  Also, ensure you have the latest VS Cordova update 7 installed - http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/03/01/announcing-update-7.html.  And double-check, because these updates are important. Lastly, what do you see when you run dependency checker for Cordova in VS?

Comment: @SteveKennedy please see the answer I posted below (thanks to the TACO team at MS).

Answer (score 2):

OK this is a weird bug which only manifests itself under the following conditions:

- The symlink (the link, not the target folder) resides under a folder called `Res` under `www`, e.g. `/www/Res/Js/SymLink`.
- The symlink is a relative path symlink and not an absolute path one.

The TACO team at Microsoft (who I was in touch with on this issue) will try to fix that bug. In the meantime, either moving the symlink out of `Res` or using an absolute path symlink both solve the issue.